# SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog not working with IE7

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I'm trying to make this link below work with IE7 but it doesn't fire.
Whereas is ok in IE9 and firefox.
Any ideas what i'm doing wrong :(
THanks

```
   <a href="#" onclick="openDialog('/Comms.aspx?sc={@ID}'); return true "><xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function openDialog(FormPath) {
    var options = {
        url: FormPath,
        width: 950,
        height: 800,
        title: "Communications",
        allowMaximize:'true',
    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove comma right after allowMaximize:'true', :)
When writing javascript always track script errors that might appear. In IE they displays in left bottom corner, you can click it to see details and also can check "Always show this message for webpage errors" and this popup will show every time when javascript errors appear.

Comment: THanks for the Kai.Missed that :(
What IE showed the error.IE7 or IE 8.
Just curious as i notice the Doen error on the let but doesn't show me the exact problem
Cheers

Comment: Cheers, solved the exact same error for me. Error only occured in IE7, worked fine in 8 & 9.

Comment: Yip.. i've seen this before. Good answer!

Comment: As an aside, I would suggest against developing for IE7. There are several CSS inconsistances that are absolutely annoying, such as ASP buttons set to be the page's "default button" rendering with an extra border as well as not being able to use `display: inline-block;` in your CSS. I noticed this when we were developing locally and our IE policy was set to run all Intranet sites in Compatibility mode which is AWFUL!